# Check how many elements of one list are contained in a second list, including duplicates

Tags: python, list, comparison

I want to compare some lists (e.g. `l2,l3`) to one big list (`l1`), based on the number of occurencies, for example:

```
l1 = ['s1', 's1', 's1', 's2']
l2 = ['s1', 's2']
l3 = ['s1', 's1', 's1']
```

In my scenario, `l1` is closer to `l3`, because (when also considering the number of occurences), the difference between l1 and l3 is only `['s2']`.

The usual approach of comparing list elements by converting them to a `set` and intersecting them does not work here, since the duplicates are removed.

I would like to have an output like this:
`compare(l1,l2) = ['s1', 's2']` ("These two elments of l2 were found in l1")
`compare(l1,l3) = ['s1', 's1', 's1']`

Is there an operator / a function to do so or a better data structure than a list?

Comment: For ```l1``` and ```l3```, are there 3 matches (one for each ```'s1'```) or 9 (each ```'s1'``` matches 3 times)?

Comment: If `l3` has an `s3` element does that increase it's distance from `l1` or is it only relevant how many `l3` matches from `l1`? Or will `l3` never have items not in `l1`?

Comment: ```s1``` occurred 3 times in both lists, therefore the distance is 3.

Comment: @MarkMeyer: if ```l3``` has an ```s3``` element, the result of ```comp(l1,l3)``` would be ```['s1', 's1', 's1', 's2']```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the intersection operator `&` of the `collections.Counter` class:

```
from collections import Counter
def compare(l1, l2):
    return list((Counter(l1) & Counter(l2)).elements())
```

So that `compare(l1, l2)` returns:

```
['s1', 's2']
```

and that `compare(l1, l3)` returns:

```
['s1', 's1', 's1']
```

Comment: TIL that `Counter` has `__and__`, `__or__` , `__neg__` interface ... thanks! :) upvote

Answer (score 0):

```
import Levenshtein as lev
from collections import Counter

def compAndPrint(idOneList, idAnotherList, oneList, anotherList):
    ratio = lev.seqratio(oneList, anotherList)
    print(idOneList, idAnotherList, ratio)
    return ratio
def makeKey (k1, k2):
    return k1 + '<=>' + k2

def listElements(oneList, anotherList):
    return list((Counter(oneList) & Counter(anotherList)).elements())

def main():
    allLists = {
        'l1': ['s1', 's1', 's1', 's2'],
        'l2': ['s1', 's2'],
        'l3': ['s1', 's1', 's1'],
        'l4': ['s1', 's2', 's2','s2', 's1', 's1'],
        'l5': ['s5', 's1', 's1', 's1', 's2'],
         }
    bestMatch = -1
    done = {}
    for xlistName in allLists.keys():
        for ylistName in allLists.keys():
            k = makeKey(xlistName, ylistName)
            kRev = makeKey(ylistName, xlistName)
            if xlistName == ylistName or kRev in done:
                continue
            ratio = compAndPrint(xlistName, ylistName, 
                         allLists[xlistName],
                         allLists[ylistName],  )
            done[k] = ratio
            if bestMatch < ratio:
                bestMatch = ratio
                xBest = xlistName
                yBest = ylistName
    print("BEST MATCH: ", makeKey(xBest, yBest), '~', bestMatch)
    print("joined elements", listElements(allLists[xBest], allLists[yBest])) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```